# How do I manage a fork of a git-svn repository?

Tags: git, version-control

Say I'm adding a new target to LLVM and I want to keep my changes on GitHub until I'm ready to submit them to upstream. LLVM maintains a Git mirror of their SVN repository and recommends using `git pull --rebase` when syncing with `upstream/master`. The plan so far is that my repository's `master` branch would track `upstream/master` and then the `mytarget` branch would have my changes.

The [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) says this, however:

> **Do not rebase commits that exist outside your repository.**

So if I want to `git pull` from `upstream/master` into `master` and `git push` back to `origin`, I *shouldn't* use `--rebase`, then? Or should I use `git pull --rebase` to sync from `upstream/master` and then do a merge from `master` into `mytarget`?

What should my overall workflow be in this situation?

Comment: A better way to put it is: "Do not rebase commits that other people may have based their work on".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git pull --rebase` rebases those commits that hasn't been pushed yet so it should be safe. Let us see…

```
A  B  c  D
*--*--*--* <master
      |
  origin/master
```

You have one not-pushed commit `D`. If there are two new commits at the remote master and you run `git pull --rebase origin/master` git pulls that two commits and rebases commit `D` on top of them:

```
A  B  c  X  Y  D`
*--*--*--*--*--* <master
            |
      origin/master
```

The new commit is `D'` (commits are never really edited or moved — git creates new commits instead and move branch pointers). Now you do `git push origin master` to push the new commit and whar we see:

```
A  B  c  X  Y  D`
*--*--*--*--*--* <master
               |
         origin/master
```

Comment: What about the sync from `master` to `mytarget`? That needs to be a merge, right? Otherwise I would need to force push because `git rebase` rewrites the history?

Comment: If `mytarget` is also in SVN — yes, you cannot rebase what you've already pushed, so merge. But if `mytarget` is not in SVN — you are free to do whatever your branching policy allows; you can rebase and force-push it, e.g.